# Why does Wordpress use cookies for /wp-admin and /wp-content/plugins for non-admin users

Tags: plugins, wp-admin, login, cookies, authentication

After login with Firefox to Wordpress website as non admin user, 3 cookies are set:

1. *wordpress_logged_in_...*
2. *wordpress_sec_...* for path */wp-admin*
3. *wordpress_sec_...* for path */wp-content/plugins*

Why are cookies 2-3 needed for non admin user?

Answer (score 0):

According to answer [here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/why-does-wp-use-cookies-for-wp-admin-and-wp-content-plugins-for-non-admin-user/#post-9934654):

> All logged in users use resources from wp-admin and plugins, not just
>   admins. The cookies are for keeping track of the logged in user’s
>   authorization to access each resource. If a visitor does not log in,
>   no cookies are set at all by default. Themes or plugins may do so
>   though.